# language problem

Tags: languages, greek

I created this command:

```
\newcommand{\NewPart}[1]{\section*{\uppercase{#1}}}
```

and run it like this:

```
\NewPart{Personal details}{}
```

My problem is that instead of 'Personal details' I want to give a name in greek. I used `babel` and ran `\selectlanguage{greek}` but it is not enough. The letters remain in English. Can you give me any idea to handle my problem?

I am new here so excuse my several mistakes. This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl}                % KOMA-article class
\usepackage[iso-8859-7]{inputenc}
\usepackage{kerkis}
\usepackage{a4}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[vcentering,dvips]{geometry}
\usepackage{calc}
\input{epsf.tex}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}                               
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm} 
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}  
\usepackage{geometry}
\textheight=700px               
\usepackage{url}          
\usepackage{wrapfig}       
\frenchspacing             
\pagestyle{empty}                               

\usepackage{sectsty}                            
\sectionfont{%                                  
\usefont{OT1}{phv}{b}{n}%                   
\sectionrule{0pt}{0pt}{-5pt}{3pt}
\newlength{\spacebox}
\settowidth{\spacebox}{888888888}              
\newcommand{\sepspace}{\vspace*{1em}}           
\newcommand{\NewPart}[1]{\section*{\uppercase{#1}}}
\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{greek}
\NewPart{Personal details}{}
\end{document}
```

When I run the tex-file "Personal details" are written in English instead of Greek despite the fact that I have already changed the language.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 5):

Removing the irrelevant packages, here's a working solution:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl}                % KOMA-article class
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[iso-8859-7]{inputenc}
\usepackage{kerkis}
\frenchspacing

\newcommand{\NewPart}[1]{\section*{\MakeUppercase{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\NewPart{Personal details}
\end{document}
```

Of course,

[image]

means nothing in Greek. But I can write nothing significant in your language. `;-)`

The problem is that you set a font that has no Greek character in it: the encoding OT1 has only Latin characters.

You shouldn't use `sectsty` along with `scrartcl`, because this class has its own methods for changing fonts of sectional units.

---

Other problems in your input.

1. The main language should be specified last, so

   ```
   \usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
   ```

   will avoid the need to say `\selectlanguage{greek}` at the start. Remove the `english` option if you don't need that language.
2. The `a4` package is obsolete. Moreover you're already loading `geometry`.
3. Don't pass the `dvips` option to `geometry`.
4. Saying `\input{epsf.tex}` has been deprecated for several years; if you have to include graphic objects say

   ```
   \usepackage{graphicx}
   ```

   and use its facilities.
5. If you want to set up the vertical size, pass it as an option to `geometry`; for instance

   ```
   \usepackage[vcentering,textheight=700pt,heightrounded]{geometry}
   ```

   but probably a length in centimeters would be more comprehensible. Don't use the `px` unit.

Comment: Thank you very much. You gave me the solution i wanted. Thank you again. Can you tell me what encoding should I use instead of OT1 to get the Greek characters?

Comment: @user2399518 The encoding is LGR; but there are not many fonts available with that encoding. Surely Helvetica (`phv`) isn't.